# ionic keyboard focus on input box issue

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using angular with ionic

I have used below code

```
<input type="number" name="foo" ng-model="field.field_value" class="form-number" ng-focus="keyboardFocus(this)" >

$scope.keyboardFocus=function(t){
            var a= $(t).attr('class');
            alert(a);  
          // $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom();
          // $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle(t).scrollTop();
            $("."+a).css('position','absolute');
            $("."+a).css('top','0px');
           }
```

But scroll is not working in current position on textbox. keyboard focus on textbox is not working but type any text foucus is  working

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: i want ionic keyboard focus in  inputbox . show the input box on top with scroll.. because keyboard overlap on inutbox so i did try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho, no need to use `$ionicScrollDelegate`, change position, scroll manually or any other complicated stuff.

You just need the [Ionic Keyboard Cordova plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) to be installed. See the explanation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/).

To install it:
`cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard`

Nothing else to do. On focus, the page will move automatically.

Of course, it will work only on real devices, but in my experience, with this plugin, focused form elements are never hidden under the keyboard.

Comment: same issue is comming

Comment: Then I don't really know what to say. I used it in multiple projects and this works like a charm for me.

For other people to help you, you should give more information: Did your try any other solutions? On which platform & browser are you testing? What is the Ionic version your are using? Etc.

Comment: not working.. i have  installed.. do i change my code?

Comment: keyboard focus on textbox is not working but type any text foucus is  working. can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Best way will be to use `$ionicScrollDelegate`, for that you need to define `delegate-handle` value on element this way:

```
<input type="number" name="foo" ng-model="field.field_value" class="form-number" delegate-handle="myInput" ng-focus="keyboardFocus('myInput')" >
```

And then pass into `keyboardFocus` this way: `ng-focus="keyboardFocus('myInput')"` .

And function will become

```
$scope.keyboardFocus=function(handleValue){    
      $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle(handleValue).scrollTop();
 }
```